How to deploy Spring boot 3 https project
I've successfully setup https on project using springboot 3 on localhost.
this is my application.yaml :
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: development
  application:
    name: meteraindo
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  datasource:
    username: root
    password: 1ron_man
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/meterai
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 50MB
      max-request-size: 50MB
    
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: info@cg2net.id
    password: findingCg2
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true
          ssl:
            protocols: TLSv1.2
server:  
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    **key-store: src/main/resources/meteraindo.p12**
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store-password: padamuNegr1
    key-alias: meteraindo
---

I can deploy it find if its not set as https. i just do mvn clean install and upload the war file.
My question is how to deploy it to my live tomcat server? When i do mvn install does springboot incorporate .p12 into war file? or do i need to upload it manually to my server?
i also uncomment this part on "server.xml"
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprPr>
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol>
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.p>
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>


please guide me how to set it up to my server.
Thanks in advance
UPDATE:
as @M. Deinum suggested using runnable jar https works (i've tested in vms) & war with provied tomcat wont work (for me).
But when i try at my hosting (alibaba) the running jar not working, oh well i guest i need additional setup at my hosting.
Thanks @M. Deinum

You need to configure the server (all server.* properties are ignored when deploying to a server). Why are you deploying and not just use the runnable jar to run the application?

using war is just the way iam familiar wth.  i'll look using runnable jar.

btw how to configure the server (all server.* properties are ignored when deploying to a server)?

The war is runnable as well. Just do java -jar your.war or java -jar your.jar and it will bootstrap just as when run from your IDE. No need to install a Tomcat server and deploy the application. All is already contained. Your server.ssl.key-store property is wrong btw is shoud be classpath:/meteraindo.p12 else it won't work from inside a jar/war file as there is no src/main/resources.

UPDATE: as @M. Deinum suggested using runnable jar https works (i've tested in vms) & war with provied tomcat wont work (for me).
